# Stripe API auto_paging get all Stripe::BalanceTransaction except some charge

Tags: ruby-on-rails, json, ruby, api, stripe-payments

I'm trying to get all **Stripe::BalanceTransaction** except those they are already in my **JsonStripeEvent**

What I did =>

```
  def perform(*args)
    last_recorded_txt = REDIS.get('last_recorded_stripe_txn_last')
      txns = Stripe::BalanceTransaction.all(limit: 100, expand: ['data.source', 'data.source.application_fee'], ending_before: last_recorded_txt)
      REDIS.set('last_recorded_stripe_txn_last', txns.data[0].id) unless txns.data.empty?
      txns.auto_paging_each do |txn|
        if txn.type.eql?('charge') || txn.type.eql?('payment')
          begin
            JsonStripeEvent.create(data: txn.to_json)
          rescue StandardError => e
            Rails.logger.error "Error while saving data from stripe #{e}"
            REDIS.set('last_recorded_stripe_txn_last', txn.id)
            break
          end
        end
      end
  end
```

But It doesnt get the new one from the API.

Can anyone could help me for this ? :)

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

I think it's because the way `auto_paging_each` works is almost opposite to what you expect :)

As you can see from its source, `auto_paging_each` calls `Stripe::ListObject#next_page`, which is implemented as follows:

```
def next_page(params={}, opts={})
  return self.class.empty_list(opts) if !has_more
  last_id = data.last.id

  params = filters.merge({
    :starting_after => last_id,
  }).merge(params)

  list(params, opts)
end
```

It simply takes the last (already fetched) item and adds its id as the `starting_after` filter.

So what happens:

- You fetch 100 "latest" (let's say) records, ordered by descending date (default order for BalanceTransaction API according to Stripe docs)
- When you call `auto_paging_each` on this dataset then, it takes the last record, adds its id as the
  `starting_after` filter and repeats the query.
- The repeated query returns nothing because there are noting newer (starting later) than the set you initially fetched.
- As far as there are no more newer items available, the iteration stops after the first step

What you could do here:

First of all, ensure that my hypothesis is correct :) - put the breakpoint(s) inside Stripe::ListObject and check. Then 1) rewrite your code to use `starting_after` traversing logic instead of `ending_before` - it should work fine with `auto_paging_each` then - or 2) rewrite your code to control the fetching order manually.

Personally, I'd vote for (2): for me slightly more verbose (probably), but straightforward and "visible" control flow is better than poorly documented magic.

Comment: Thanks Konstantin ! 
I'll try to make it work today, Im keeping you in touch !